# C++ Program glitch?

Tags: c++

I need help debugging my code. So I made a program that adds and subtracts numbers but when I implemented a do-while loop to replay the program, the actual program closes and does not perform the do-while loop and does not replay the program. Is their something wrong with my code?

P.S. I am also using codeblocks IDE

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    // Addition and Subtraction Calculator

    int a_number, number1, number2, sum, number3, number4, subsum, again;
    // subsum = subtracted sum
    // number1 and number2 are variables that hold the users input for addition 
    // number3 and number4 are variables that hold the users input for     subtraction                

    do
    {
        cout << "Addition & Subtraction Calculator" << endl;
        cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;

        cout << "1. Addition" << endl;
        cout << "2. Subtraction" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter a number [1 or 2]" << endl;
        cin >> a_number;

        while (a_number < 1 || a_number > 2)
        {
            cout << "Please enter either 1 or 2" << endl;
            cin >> a_number;
        }

        switch (a_number)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Please enter a number" << endl;
            cin >> number1;
            cout << "Please enter another number" << endl;
            cin >> number2;
            sum = (number1 + number2);
            cout << "The sum is " << sum << endl;
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "Please enter a number" << endl;
            cin >> number3;
            cout << "Please enter another number" << endl;
            cin >> number4;
            subsum = (number3 - number4);
            cout << "The answer to the subtraction problem is: " << subsum << endl;
            break;
        }

        cout << "Do you want to try again? [y/n]" << endl;
        cin >> again;
    }
    while (again == 'y' || again == 'n');


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you indent your code properly?

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: `cin >> again;` you know `again` is an `int`, right? So... what exactly are you expecting will happen when you enter `y` or `n` rather than a valid `int` ?

Answer (score 1):

OK. So the OP is using an `int` where they should have used a `char`. That covers the immediate problem. `int again` should be `char again`.

But there is an important point the other answers have missed.

```
int again;
cin >> again;
```

The user input will be converted into an integer as required by `again`. Inputting y or n fails to convert to an integer as neither y nor n are numbers and cannot be converted. `again` remains unchanged, keeping whatever junk value happened to be sitting at that spot in memory and *might actually be a y or an n*, but more importantly `cin` is now in an error state that needs to be cleared before continuing.

`cin` would have notified the OP of this if it had been tested. So let's test it.

```
int again;
if (cin >> again)
{
     // got good input. Do something with it.
}
else
{
     // got bad input. 
     cin.clear();
     // that bad input is still in the buffer and needs to be removed
     cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
     // the above line will wipe out everything to the end of the stream or 
     // end of line, whichever comes first. 
}
```

Why this is important: Because the OP is doing a lot of numeric input with `cin` and none  of it is checked for validity. For example:

```
cout << "Please enter a number [1 or 2]" << endl;
cin >> a_number;
```

The program is broken completely and cannot exit without a kill signal if the user types in anything but a number.

Always check the error state and return codes. They are there to help. Always validate user input before using it. Users are evil and will try to break your program. Don't let them.

Answer (score 0):

use `char again;` instead of `int again;`

in your code `again` is `int` and when in `(again == 'y' || again == 'n')`you compare `again` (an `int`) with a `char`, that does not make sense

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the again variable to a char datatype because you need to store text. Something like this:

```
char again;
```

You also need to change the while statement to:

```
while(again != "n");
```

Or

```
while(again == "y");
```